# How update Google form display after changing file name with script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm using a Google form with multiples subpart (Multiple choices, Short answer...) and one upload file box.

When I upload a file, the name of the logged user is added into the file name. I don't want this.

So I use a Google script to change their name, it's ok in the folder directory (the file names are correctly updated), but in the Google form display ("Responses" section), there is always the old names.

How can I force the refresh of the Form display ?

Here is my script :

```
function myFunction() {
  var existingForm = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var formResponses = existingForm.getResponses();


for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
  var formResponse = formResponses[i];
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();

  for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
    var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
    var title = itemResponse.getItem().getTitle();
    
   var files = itemResponse.getResponse();
   for (var n in files) {
       var my_file = files[n];
       var dFile = DriveApp.getFileById(my_file);
       var dFileName = dFile.getName();
       dFile.setName("New name " + n);
    }
  }
}
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon checking the available methods and Form Settings, there is no way to change the file names under **Responses** even if the actual file in the directory/folder is already renamed.

Even the Forms UI doesn't provide any way of renaming the uploaded file name under **Responses** so it is highly unlikely to be supported in Apps Script as well.

Comment: Thanks NaziA for your feedback, I had the same feeling unfortunately :(

Comment: Hi @vanessa, if this answered your question, please click the accept/upvote button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved or not. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)